# Transfer data from SQL Server 2008 to MySQL Workbench using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to transfer data from SQL Server (~100k rows) to MySQL server via C# application. Is it the best way to transfer data to the `listView` (for example) first, read this data and then insert it to MySQL? Or, what can serve as an alternative to keep this data in some buffer in order to transfer this data to MySQL? There are 4 columns in the table, 2 of which are table data (`pay_type` and `pay_amount`), and values from other 2 columns I need to take from `.INI` file (`market_name` and `transaction_date`).

Comment: Maybe use file? Import data to CSV from SQLServer and export to MySQL?

Comment: Is it compatible with c#?

Comment: When transferring from an old FoxPro database to MySQL - I used the OleDbConnection and MySqlConnection classes. Querying the FoxPro tables into a DataSet & then using that DataSet as the source for the update to the MySQL tables.

Comment: @PaulF I used DataSet, but only for 2 columns from the table. How to add another 2 columns (which are not from database)?

Comment: The DataSet could be modified to add the two columns & then update the dataset with the additional data. Or update the MySQL table first & then run a second query to add the data from the .INI files.Without knowing more about your data it's hard to say - how do you match up the two sets of data at the moment?

Comment: @PaulF I think I understood. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

If it's a once-and-done requirement, you'd be well advised to use tools to export your data from SQL Server to a .csv or tab-separated-value file, then import them to MySQL.

SQL Server Management Studio will write the csv files. HeidiSQL or phpMyAdmin will import them.

There are many other tools available for free or cheap.

If it's an ongoing requirement, you should write a simple C# program with this outline:

```
  open connections to sql-server and mysql 
  turn off autocommit on mysql
  execute "select whatever from table" on sql server
  while (rdr.Read) {
      execute "insert into table ..." on mysql
      every hundredth row, commit on mysql
  }
  commit on mysql
```